# Question regarding English in an old maths book

Tags: meaning

I'm currently working through an old British maths book, released around 1910, on the whole the language is quite manageable however I've reached a part of the text where there's talk of circles and this was written:

> "The circumferences of circles are to one another as their radii"

What does this mean? Does it mean that the circumference of circles are dependent on their radii or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the ratio of one circle's circumference to another's, is the same as the ratio of the radii of the same circles.  Or *c1/c2 = r1/r2*, where c1 and c2 are the circumferences of two circles, and r1 and r2 are the radii of the same circles.

Comment: Also c1/c2 = r1/r2, where c1 = 2πr1 and c2 = 2πr2 are circumferences of two circles, and r1 and r2 are the radii of the same circles.

Comment: Oh yes, I did rather get that wrong, didn't I!  Fixed it now :)